# Certbot in Raspbian Jessie: It doesn't work

Tags: raspbian-jessie, web-server

I'm using a R-pi 1 Model B+ but my problem is more of a software thing. I'm using my pi as an experimental server and I'm excited about making a certificate for it so it's "secure". Well, I'm using nginx and I followed the instructions on https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianjessie-nginx

When I run:

```
$ sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/example -d example.com -d www.example.com -w /var/www/thing -d thing.is -d m.thing.is
```

or

```
$ sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Changing the folders and domains to my own I just don't get any response from the application. It's installed but I get no error,and yet no certificate. What can I do?

Comment: Is your server (nginx) visible to the internet (i.e. most home users are behind a NAT router, you have to configure the router to redirect incoming http requests to your pi (port 80 and 443) for this letsencrypt to work0

Comment: I think you still need to move the certificates to where nginx expects to find them.

Comment: My pi is visible from the internet, Jaromanda. Gerard, where?